# Trying to attach a save script in unity, serialization not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi trying to attach a simple save script into a GameObject (cube) in unity. everything looks fine ( no errors) except for the Serialize part(says 'no overload for method 'Serialize' takes 1 arguments) . can anyone guide me on this?. here is the example of the code. thanks a lot!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class SavingTheGame : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collider)
    {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.dat");


           bf.Serialize(file);
            file.Close();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not serializing anything, you need to supply the object you would like to serialize

```
public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collider)
{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/SaveGame.dat");

       // Change here
       var obj = "This Will Be Serialized";
       bf.Serialize(file, obj); 

       file.Close();     
}
```

BinaryFormatter.Serialize requires 2 parameters, stream and object

You can follow a nice tutorial on using BinaryFormatter in Unity for saving/loading here: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934

Comment: Thanks Paradrox Forge, the code is fine now, no errors, however SaveGame.data did not appear in my folder when i pass through the game Object. what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you checking the assets folder? Application.persistentDataPath will save somewhere in the user directory, not where your project is.

Comment: Add a Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath) to see where it saves to.

Comment: Hi Paradox Forge, i've checked areas around user directory, its still not there.  any advice??

Comment: Hi Paradox Forge, thanks for helping. Added the Debug log and it worked!